# Get all Magento Categories using SQL query

Tags: magento-1.8, database, sql, category-attribute

I have this SQL to get all Magento Categories.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    cc.entity_id AS id,
    cc.`value` AS path,
    cc1.`value` AS `NAME`,
    cce.`level`,
    cce.parent_id
FROM
    catalog_category_entity_varchar cc
JOIN catalog_category_entity_varchar cc1 ON cc.entity_id = cc1.entity_id
JOIN eav_entity_type ee ON cc.entity_type_id = ee.entity_type_id
JOIN catalog_category_entity cce ON cc.entity_id = cce.entity_id
WHERE
    cc.attribute_id = '57'
AND cc1.attribute_id = '41'
AND ee.entity_model = 'catalog/category'
```

This returns all categories, but I created a new category from Magento backend but that is not showing.

That category is published and has no products in it.
Following image is from `catalog_category_entity_varchar` table.

[image]

`entity_id = 449` is showing when I run that query, because it has `attribute_id = 57 and 41`

But I am talking about `entity_id = 452` that is not showing, because it does not have `attribute_id = 57`.

I want to ask Magento experts, what does `attribute_id = 57` belong to? and how can I fix this query to fetch all categories?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you use an implicit `INNER JOIN` and define the join conditions for attribute tables in `WHERE` clauses.

That means, if there is no value saved for one of the attributes with ID 41 and 57, you get no results.

Improved version with `LEFT JOIN` on the attribute tables and the entity table as main table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    main_table.entity_id AS id,
    at_path.`value` AS path,
    at_name.`value` AS `NAME`,
    main_table.`level`,
    main_table.parent_id
FROM
    catalog_category_entity main_table

JOIN
    eav_entity_type ee
ON
    main_table.entity_type_id = ee.entity_type_id AND ee.entity_model = 'catalog/category'

LEFT JOIN
    catalog_category_entity_varchar at_path
ON
    at_path.entity_id=main_table.entity_id AND at_path.attribute_id = 57

LEFT JOIN
    catalog_category_entity_varchar at_name
ON
    at_name.entity_id=main_table.entity_id AND at_name.attribute_id = 41
```

Now the column for attribute 57 (which is `url_path`) will show up as `NULL` in the result if there is no value.

Answer (score 1):

I think, there is an attribute with ID = 57. You can check it in database table `eav_attribute`.

In admin Category section, For `entity_id = 449` (categoryId 449), there might some value set for this attribute. And for `entity_id = 452` (categoryId 452), 
this value will be empty (I mean not set). You can add some value in this attribute for this entity, then do SAVE (and re-index if needed)

Now run query, you can see `entity_id = 452`.

**UPDATE**: Here attribute_id = 57 is category attribute :  `url_path`. Please run `Catalog URL Rewrites` index. This will set the value of this attribute for All categories.

Make sure, you set `Index Mode` to `Update on Save`

Comment: `57 3 url_path   varchar   text    0 0  0` this is the ROW with ID = 57 in that table ...

Comment: its the URL PATH ... but how can I add URL path to a category in backend? is that the `URL Key` option in category backend? I have already set that to some value and that is not empty

Comment: I think, you need to run re-index. Check updated answer

Comment: Does magento work that way? I mean I have added URL KEY from backend and it still didnt INSERTED that row into DB? still need to re-index

Comment: `Catalog URL Rewrites` is set to `Update on Save` OR `Manual Update` ? If its set to `Manual Update` then you have to re-index manually Otherwise it will run auto on Updating/Saving category